# Subtract return incorrect date

Tags: php

I'm trying to subtract 3 years from a date, but I get: 1970-01-01, check:

```
$start_date = $this->db->escape(date('Y-m-d'));
$end_date = $this->db->escape(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date . ' -3 year')));
```

Comment: Try creating the dates before you pass it through escape. The date functions work fine for me. It could be because you're running start_date through escape, which could be messing with the actual date.

Comment: print date('Y-m-d',strtotime(' -3 year'));  work

Comment: Based on the use of something like `db->escape` I an fairly sure Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: And as none of this data seems to be user input, there is not much point in escaping it anyway

Comment: the start date is '2019-02-13' and end date without the escape is still 1970-01-01, and yes I use the parametererized query

Comment: If you use prepared and parameterised queries, then escaping is not necessary

Comment: the solution of @FAEWZX works don't know why mine not

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh didn't know that, thanks

Comment: Works here without escape https://3v4l.org/m7uDu

Comment: This works also `$d = strtotime('2019-02-13' . ' -3 year');
echo date('Y-m-d', $d);`

Comment: Can you show the `var_dump($start_date);`?

Answer (score 0):

In an OOP approach you may want to use something like this:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
echo $now->sub(new \DateInterval("P3Y"))->format("Y-m-d");
```

So I adapted your code and this should work for you:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$start_date = $this->db->escape($now->format("Y-m-d"));
$end_date = $this->db->escape($now->sub(new \DateInterval("P3Y"))->format("Y-m-d"));
```